# Django Admin panel unable to retrieve and show image(already uploaded through model)

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

As you can see in SS i am unable to view the image in admin panel; under the image tag

error from CMD:

```
Not Found: /upload/images/How-to-buy-a-desktop-PC-header.jpg
[27/Jun/2021 13:00:51] "GET /upload/images/How-to-buy-a-desktop-PC-header.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2605
```

I already checked the upload folder and image is in the folder.

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/upload/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'upload')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

models.py

```
# under the Product class
    
    def image_tag(self):
        return mark_safe('<img src="{}" height ="50"/>'.format(self.image.url))

    image_tag.short_discription = 'Image'
```

last admin.py

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'category', 'status', 'image_tag']
    list_filter =['category']
    readonly_fields = ('image_tag',)
    inline = [ProductImageInline]
```

screenshot:
[image: Django Admin Panel]

Comment: Are you running it using ./manage.py runserver?

Comment: Yes, i am using manage.py runserver. After uploading the image in the product, admin panel does not shows any image in the panel.

Comment: Can you make sure that the images are actually uploaded in upload/images/ folder?

Comment: yes, i just checked by adding a new product and images are uploading( checked the upload folder) correctly but unable to view in the admin panel.

Comment: one more thing i dont know why it shows image tag instead of image